# My email intents text display format is not right advice please

Tags: android, email, android-intent, text, formatting

i have 3 text inputs like below:

`name   _____ <e.g JohnMclain`  "<--only a example haha"

`date   _____ <e.g 09/09/13`

`phone  _____ <e.g 09765432100`

when i click send button its displays like this in the emails message:
name:John Mclaindate:09/09/13phone:09765432100

i need it to be in seperate lines like:

> Name:John Mclain
>
> Date:09/09/13
>
> Phone:0976543100`

my code works it like this:

```
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "A message");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Text1 + Name + Text2 + Phone + Text3 + Date);
```

Why is is coming up like this?

I have also tried below code. the Date and Text3 are the only ones that come up in email message

```
 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Text1 + Name);
 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Text2 + Phone);
 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Text3 + Date);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Text1 + Name + "\n" + Text2 + Phone + "\n" + Text3 + Date);
```

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH. ive been at that all day

Comment: Do you know how to do checkboxes. I only want the check boxes emailed to me if its checked. I have about 5 check boxes. Would sort of code would I use to do this. Thanks

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-checkbox-example/ has a good tutorial on checkboxes.